# Using JS reduce() on base of map()

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
let authors = [
  { firstName: "Beatrix", lastName: "Potter" },
  { firstName: "Ann", lastName: "Martin" },
];
```

I want to unify the details after mapping the array items with `map()`, then reduce the objects to a single string with `reduce()` so the output would be `"Beatrix Potter", "Ann Martin"`.

I have tried the following code but failed:

```
fullAuthorNames = authors.map( (e)=> 
    authors.reduce( (firstName, lastName)=> firstName + lastName );
);
```

This is the relevant output:

> ["[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object
>   Object]","[object Object][object Object][object Object][object
>   Object][object Object]"

What did I do wrong here? Maybe I didn't target the objects inside the array right?

Comment: because you are adding objects together.... you are not working on the keys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't need a `reduce`, just `map` then `join` the result array:

```
let fullAuthorNames = authors.map(a => a.firstName + " " + a.lastName).join(", ");
```

**Example:**

```js
let authors = [
  { firstName: "Beatrix", lastName: "Potter" },
  { firstName: "Ann", lastName: "Martin" },
];


let fullAuthorNames = authors.map(a => a.firstName + " " + a.lastName).join(", ");

console.log(fullAuthorNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the each object to a string using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the results to a string:

```js
const authors = [
  { firstName: "Beatrix", lastName: "Potter" },
  { firstName: "Ann", lastName: "Martin" },
];

const result = authors.map(({ firstName, lastName }) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`)
  .join(', '); // remove this if you want an array of strings

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.Map converts an array to another array.  Array.Reduce aggregates an array into a value.  They're typically used in serial.

Try:

```
fullAuthorNames = authors.map(  (e)=> e.firstName + ' ' + e.lastName )
                         .reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) =>
                                  accumulator + (index ? ', ' : '') + currentValue, '');
```

'join', as in the answers above is probably simpler, but not quite what you asked.